# Best way to pull the request-URI from an HTTP header in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking

Bear with me as I know this question seems easily searchable but I've been stuck on it for some time and would greatly appreciate a thorough read-through before answering. I'm trying to write a very basic Java server, not to be scaled or implemented but just to understand networking. What is the best (in this case, simplest) method of parsing a request header to extract the filename? My current code uses a Socket to establish the connection, and in doing research I've seen:

1. Reading the socket's inputstream into a scanner/buffered reader and manually parsing it (by the leading / before the filename, I'm assuming)
2. Using default methods of HttpServletRequest (how do you generate an object of this type? Isn't an interface non-instantiable? Documentation is unclear about this)
3. Something with a "Content-Disposition Header"?

Thanks again for the help, these http API's seem very similar/overlapping to a rookie network programmer.

Comment: You need to have a grasp of [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) before you progress too far...

Comment: I have a grasp of it, but I think I'm confused because the guidelines I'm following provide a rough outline of the project and start by establishing a socket connection, but then reference HTTP API's and classes which I thought were distinct from socket programming

Comment: HttpServletRequest is part of the servlet API which defines some interfaces for the same thing that you are attempting. It may be more enlightening to have a look at the source for Tomcat or Undertow (open source implementations of the servlet API) and see how they do it if this is a learning exercise.